# When building react-native app: undefined symbols for architecture gxx_personality_v0

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm just following the react native docs to build an app to run on device or release it [1].

I'm encountering the following error, even on a freshly new react native app. The app runs just fine in the simulator.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "___gxx_personality_v0",
>   referenced from:
>             _RCTDefaultLogFunction_block_invoke in libReact.a(RCTLog.o)
>             _RCTFormatLog in libReact.a(RCTLog.o)
>             ___RCTAddLogFunction_block_invoke in libReact.a(RCTLog.o)
>             _RCTPerformBlockWithLogFunction in libReact.a(RCTLog.o)
>             _RCTPerformBlockWithLogPrefix in libReact.a(RCTLog.o)
>             RCTGetLocalLogFunction() in libReact.a(RCTLog.o)
>             ___RCTPerformBlockWithLogPrefix_block_invoke in libReact.a(RCTLog.o)
>             ...
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm basically doing

```
react-native init SampleApp
... generates app
react-native run-ios # works fine (on simulator)
react-native run-ios --configuration Release # fails with the error above.
```

It fails with the same if I open the XCode project, change the Scheme to Release, and try to build.

What's happening? Looks like I'm missing a library? How do I check it's there?  (I'm new to both react native and iOS, so don't assume I know much :)

Thanks!

--

[1] https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error and solved it via these instructions:

I just fixed this by deleting and creating my scheme in Xcode (credit goes to this SO post). Here's what I did in Xcode 7.3.1:

```
Open your project in Xcode.
Click Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes.
Select the scheme for your project, then click the minus (—) near the 
    bottom left to delete it.
Now click the plus (+) to create a new scheme for your project.
```

That's all I had to do, hth :)